# Android how after click on a button and goes to a facebook account from app?

Tags: android, facebook

Please help me to find a code where after click on a button, you are immediately redirect on a facebook account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking "yourButton" will open the facebook account associated with String "facebookURL" in the facebook app if installed and web browser if not.

```
//Set an onClickListener to yourButton
    findViewById(R.id.yourButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String facebookURL = "your url...";

            //format the facebook URL to URI if app is installed
            try {
                ApplicationInfo applicationInfo
                        = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
                if (applicationInfo.enabled) {
                    facebookURL = "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + facebookURL;
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {}

            //open facebook account
            Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookURL));
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

Note that the "facebookURL" may require the app scoped user id facebook URL which is different from the URL that contains the user name or screen name. The user id can be obtained through the Facebook Graph API. once the user id is obtained, the full URL looks like the following

```
String facebookURL = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/" + id;
```

Comment: Many thanks I tried your code and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of ways. Your question is a bit unclear.
To open facebook application on button click, following code must be called in the onClickListener for the button.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to open a facebook account on a web browser after click